# Exception : [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have been trying to configure the build path of the JSTL jar file in each and every tomcat server from the 8.5 version to 9 to 10 after adding the JSTL zar file to the path when I add the JSTL core tag it always throws an exception i.e. "**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**". For a better understanding of the issue I have shared the screenshots of all:
[image]

**Here are the two projects having two different tomcat versions 8.5 and 9 and also the configuration of JSTL 1.2 is done**
[image]

**And the code in which the core tag is included**
[image]

**And the error**

And ya it is not a maven project so no pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these two jars in your build path

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl/1.2

( https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/jstl-api/1.2/jstl-api-1.2.jar )

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl-api/1.2

( https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2-sources.jar )

( you can also download jars from the links in "(   )" )

Also, Tomcat 10, does not work with Spring 5, so you should stay on Tomcat 9 until Spring 6 is out.
That is because Spring 5 supports javax packages, and Tomcat 10 renamed javax to jakarta, so at the moment, Spring 6 will cover jakarta packages.

Comment: Still not working I added those two mentioned jar files and tomcat version is 9.0.55 still throwing that same error. Btw am a JOJO fan too.